# Trigger the Wi-Fi Hotspot every Time I start up my os

Tags: bash, scripts, automation

every time I want to open the wifi hotspot to my mobile device I go to `settings -> wifi -> Turn on Wifi hotspot`, but this start to be boring for me especially when I'm doing this a lot, what I want to accomplish is to write a bash script to automate this process every time I boot up my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a modern version of Ubuntu, then you can do this with "Startup Applications":

1. Open "Startup Applications":
   [image: Startup Applications]
2. Add a new record like this:
   [image: nmcli To the Rescue]
   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `<Your SSID>` with the SSID (name) that you gave to your hotspot.</sup>
3. Press [Add] (or [Save]) and close the application

That's all there is to it. Now, every time you log into Ubuntu, the hotspot will be started.

Comment: How to get the SSID??

Comment: You are the person who named your WiFi hotspot, that is your SSID 

Comment: hahaha, I just  figured out that it's a combination of characters, Thank you matigo